# Material UI React - Autocomplete - How to reset the internal state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

My goal is to reset the internal state of **Autocomplete** Material-UI's component.

My custom component is rendered N times in my cycle

```
{branches.map((branch, index) => {
    return (
        <BranchSetting
            key={index}
            index={index}
            data={branch}
            removeBranch={removeBranch}
        />

    )
})}
```

**branch** is my hook state.

This is my **removeBranch** function:

```
const removeBranch = (index) => {
    let listBranch = branches;
    listBranch.splice(index, 1);
    setBranches([...listBranch]);
}
```

Every time I delete an item to my array **branch**, everything works fine except the **Autocomplete**.

This is my **BranchSetting** component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const BranchSettings = ({ removeBranch, index, branchModify, data }) => {
    const [ brands, setBrands ] = useState(data.brands);

    const handleBrandSelected = (event, payload) => {
        const values = payload.map(item => item.value);
        setBrands(values);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setBrands(data.brands);
    }, [data])

    return (
        <>
            <Autocomplete
                id={'branch-brand'}
                multiple
                disableCloseOnSelect
                options={carsBrand}
                getOptionLabel={(carsBrand) => carsBrand.label}
                onChange={handleBrandSelected}
                renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                    value.map((option, index) => (
                        <Chip
                            variant="outlined"
                            label={option.value}
                            size="small"
                            {...getTagProps({ index })}
                        />
                    ))
                }
                renderInput={(params) => {
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            variant="filled"
                            fullWidth
                            label={'brand'}
                        />
                    )
                }}    
            />
        </>
    )
}
export default BranchSettings
```

**carsBrand** it is my data source that in the example I avoided writing the population. It's an array

Everytime I try to delete an item, Autocomplete keep the state of the component ad the prev position.
I'm looking a way to reset all the internal state of Autocomplete component.
The status I refer to can be seen with the *devToolBar*

[image]

I'm looking a good way to keep the items selected properly or that every time the component has changed, rerender the Autocomplete component.

Comment: How does the `branch` object looks like. can you share de properties ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami `branch` is an obj with a lot of keys... the ones that interest in this case are `index` that is a progressive number and the array `brand` with all the elements I've selected in my Autocomplete component

Comment: does it contains a unique id or unique label?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

The problem was that **Autocomplete** component need to input an array of objects with *label* and *value* keys.

In the function **handleBrandSelected** I saved into my brands status just the value. I should have saved the whole object because then it must be sent as input in **Autocomplete** with the props **value**.
And to handle the object I should have also used props **getOptionSelected**.

No problems with the remove function, and no problems with indexes. Only the values selected in inputs and compliant with the documentation were missing.
So this is the new code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const BranchSettings = ({ removeBranch, index, branchModify, data }) => {
    const [ brands, setBrands ] = useState(data.brands);

    const handleBrandSelected = (event, payload) => setBrands(payload);

    useEffect(() => {
        setBrands(data.brands);
    }, [data])

    return (
        <>
            <Autocomplete
                id={'branch-brand'}
                multiple
                disableCloseOnSelect
                options={carsBrand}
                getOptionLabel={(carsBrand) => carsBrand.label}
                onChange={handleBrandSelected}
                renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                    value.map((option, index) => (
                        <Chip
                            variant="outlined"
                            label={option.value}
                            size="small"
                            {...getTagProps({ index })}
                        />
                    ))
                }
                renderInput={(params) => {
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            variant="filled"
                            fullWidth
                            label={'brand'}
                        />
                    )
                }}
                getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
                value={brands}  
            />
        </>
    )
}
export default BranchSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably caused by using the array index as a key in `<BranchSetting key={index}`. I recommend that you add a unique id when creating the `branch` object, and use that id as a key instead. You can use `performance.now()` or a small lib like [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid).

You can read more about the negative impacts of using an index as a key [here](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: Hey mate! Thank you so much for your answer but there wasn't any problem with id and index. I resolved with another way. Check my answer ;)